# Updating old url to new url in PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am trying to change the start_url of my PWA app from one page to another but need to understand the working. Can anyone please tell me what will happen to users of my PWA app user (with old `start_url`). Is there any some kind of update happen after which old user can get the updated `start_url`.

For example:

PWA with old start_url: `www.testweb.com/oldurl`

PWA with new start_url: `www.testweb.com/newurl`

will users of PWA with old URL will get any URL after I change the `start_url`.

Comment: I'm surprised there's no answer as I have the same problem and I would have thought it was a common issue. I wonder if you simply set a redirect from the old to the new url, would that work?

Comment: Could be even more challenging if the new URL is at a different server, domain.

Answer (score 1):

With Chrome, it depends on whether you're on desktop or mobile. On desktop, changing the `start_url` will have no effect, but on Android, it should be updated within a day or two. See [How Chrome handles updates to the web app manifest](https://web.dev/manifest-updates/) for details about how manifest changes affect an installed PWA.

My recommendation would be don't change the `start_url` but instead, use the service worker to redirect the browser to the new page. For example, you could use something like:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  // Check if URL is old start_url, if so redirect to new URL
  if (event.request.url.endsWith('/previous/start_url.html')) {
    const resp = Response.redirect('/new/start_url.html', 301);
    event.respondWith(resp);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It works perfectly, although I work a little differently with the URL verification. I have a slightly different case here. Many thanks!